# GlobalVariables for my webform app

Tags: variables, module

I have a problem  with creating  GlobalVariables for my webform app.
I am creating a webform app with Visual Studio 2015, VB.net, ASP.net
I followed the instruction that I found on this and other sites but with no successs.
I did the folowwing:

1 Create the module file: Module1.vb
With this scripts:

Public Module GlobalVariables2
    Public ModuleEMAIL As String = "ModuleEMAIL@zzzzzzzz"
End Module

Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared Property clasEMAIL As String = "clasEMAIL@zzzzzzzz"
End Class

2. But when ever I try to call the variables  a compiler error occur.

Function fnBtnText()
            Button1.Text = GlobalVariables.clasEMAIL
' generate: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'GlobalVariables' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
          Button2.Text = ModuleEMAIL
```

'generate: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'ModuleEMAIL' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
        End Function

What meas “protection level” in this case?
When the scripts are moved tot another spacename area the same happens.
What am I doing wrong? Did I missed something?
I hope someone van help me out.
Many greatigs, Ton Daamen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem with your solution is, but your code worked for me when I created a new solution.

Try this:-

**GlobalForm.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="GlobalForm.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.GlobalForm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="But1"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="But2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Public Class GlobalForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Text = GlobalVariables.clasEMAIL
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button2.Text = ModuleEMAIL
    End Sub

End Class
```

**GlobalVariables Class**

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared Property clasEMAIL As String = "clasEMAIL@zzzzzzzz"
End Class
```

**GlobalVariables2 Module**

```
Module GlobalVariables2
    Public ModuleEMAIL As String = "ModuleEMAIL@zzzzzzzz"
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for he repllies.
I finaly find out what I did wrong.

A function call tot a globalvariable must be made in a .ASPX.VB file .
I did that in the .ASPX file  whitin a vb script caiuse.
Very stuppod of me.
Now it works OK. 
 Ton